# Accessing marklogic using one node in cluster is slow

Tags: java, rest, cluster-computing, load-balancing, marklogic

I am having **Marklogic Cluster** with 5 nodes and accessing marklogic through only one node, that is using **Java REST API**.

I am observing that accessing cluster using one node is very slow compared to a single host marklogic setup.

I am not sure how marklogic cluster should be accessed. Using any host in cluster or by having load balancer and then connect to load balancer from my application to access marklogic.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to utilize a MarkLogic cluster to maximize the available resources is to balance the load across the cluster.  This can be implemented in different ways, either by creating database client objects for each host, or by using a load balancer.

[Notes on Using the Java Client API efficiently](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/435/0/notes-on-using-the-java-client-api-efficiently)

[Connecting Through a Load Balancer](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/intro#id_78775)

[Transaction Management When Using a Load Balancer](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_46727)